# .htaccess редирект зацикливается

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, redirect

Есть сайт на joomla. Пытаюсь настроить редирект с домена www.domain.ru на domain.ru. Следующий конфиг приводит к зацикливанию редиректа. Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8 php_value register_globals 0Options +FollowSymLinksRewriteEngine OnRewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR] RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR] RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR] RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [F,L]RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$ [NC] RewriteRule (.*) /RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот что вы у вас происходит

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Перевожу.

> Запросики которые пришли на www.либыесимволы  [без учета регистра]
>
> Перенаправлять "весь запрос" наhttp://"весь запрос"/uri [перемещенопостоянно, последнее правило]

Т.е вы пришли на www.site.com/porno и вы делаете редирект на http://www.site.com/porno, т.е на туда же, и все повторяется.Вам надо так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Переправил:    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.ru$    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]Все равно зацикливает